# Creating Dataframe from dictionary that has multiple values assigned to each key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a very beginner in using pandas and Dataframes.
This is the dictionary :

```
names_values = {"Alex":[1,2,3,4,5],"Sam":[5,6,7,8,9]}
```

I want the Dataframe to look like this :

```
   name  value
0  Alex    1.0
1  Alex    2.0
2  Alex    3.0
3  Alex    4.0
4  Alex    5.0
5   Sam    5.0
6   Sam    6.0
7   Sam    7.0
8   Sam    8.0
9   Sam    9.0
```

My approach is :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":[],"value":[]})

for name in names_values.keys():
    for i in range(len(names_values[name])):
        df = df.append({"name": name, "value": names_values[name][i]}, ignore_index=True)
```

This gave me the result i want, but i am wondering if there is a generic/more efficient way to get the same result.
Thanks

Comment: without `range(len())` - `for name, values  in names_values.items(): for number in values: df = df.append(... "value": number, ...)`

Comment: df append is quite expensive ...

Comment: it’s probably best to modify your dictionary ahead of time instead of appending one row at a time to your dataframe since that can be slow as data size grows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using [`pandas.Dataframe.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(names_values).melt(var_name='name')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name  value
0  Alex      1
1  Alex      2
2  Alex      3
3  Alex      4
4  Alex      5
5   Sam      5
6   Sam      6
7   Sam      7
8   Sam      8
9   Sam      9
```

Comment: whoa cool ... i had no idea about this .. i was gonna make N dataframes and concat once ... but this is way better

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to modify your dictionary and then load it in.

```
from itertools import cycle

cols = ['name', 'value']
d = []

for k, v in names_values.items():
    vals = zip(cycle([k]), v)
    d.extend(list(vals))

pd.DataFrame(d, columns=cols)

   name  value
0  Alex      1
1  Alex      2
2  Alex      3
3  Alex      4
4  Alex      5
5   Sam      5
6   Sam      6
7   Sam      7
8   Sam      8
9   Sam      9
```

Another option is [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
from itertools import repeat

for k, v in names_values.items():
    vals = zip(repeat(k), v)
    d.extend(list(vals))

...
```